# How do you remove a file from a github repo

Tags: github

I realize this is a stupid question, but how does one delete a file from a git repo properly? I recently ran into an issue where I had a unit test that, due to non-trivial changes to the code would always fail. I then followed the steps outlined [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/deleting-files-in-a-repository) to delete the unit test. The next time I tried to push my changes to origin, I got a message saying my branch was out of date (or some such thing) and it recommended I do a pull request. I did a pull request and got a warning saying merging was aborted due to the file that I had deleted. So I found myself in the situation in which I could neither push nor pull my branch. I "solved" this my creating a backup copy of my work, reseting my branch then manually copying the changes I wished to make back to my working copy. Is this the "only way" to do it or is there an easy way out of this predicament? I am not so familiar with git to know any tricks that might have gotten me out of this.

I see there is some [rm](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) command that I could have followed but it is not clear to me if this is any easier than what I did, so I am looking to see if there is a more practical way out of the above situation.